# Distribution of the test statistic?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

Let $\{ \mathbf{x}_1, \cdots, \mathbf{x}_d \}$, where $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, be random vectors distributed as $\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol\mu, \boldsymbol\Sigma)$. Let $\mathbf{S}_0$ and $\mathbf{S}_1$ denote sample covariance matrix such that

$\mathbf{S}_0 = \frac{1}{d}\sum_{i=1}^d \mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{x}_i^T$ and

$\mathbf{S}_1 = \frac{1}{d}\sum_{i=1}^d (\mathbf{x}_i-\bar{\mathbf{x}})( \mathbf{x}_i - \bar{\mathbf{x}})^T$

Let $\{ \lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n \}$ and $\{ \eta_1, \cdots, \eta_n \}$ denote the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{S}_0$ and $\mathbf{S}_1$ respectively arranged in decreasing order. Let $t_{glr}$ be the test statistic which is given as

$t_{glr} = \sum_{i=r+1}^{n} \left[ \frac{1}{\eta_i} - \frac{1}{\lambda_i}\right]$, where $1 < r < n$.

Is it possible to find a distribution of $t_{glr}$?

Comment: The closest approximation that I can think of is $t_{glr} = tr\{ (\mathbf{S}_1)^{-1} - (\mathbf{S}_0)^{-1} \}$.

Comment: $t_{glr} = tr\{ (\mathbf{S}_1)^{−1}−(\mathbf{S}_0)^{−1}\}$ can be further simplified using the following identity $\mathbf{S}_1  =\mathbf{S}_0 - \bar{\mathbf{x}}(\bar{\mathbf{x}})^T$

Comment: On simplification this gives rise to $t_{glr} = \frac{\bar{\mathbf{x}}^T \mathbf{S}_1^{-2} \bar{\mathbf{x}} }{1 + \bar{\mathbf{x}}^T \mathbf{S}_1^{-1} \bar{\mathbf{x}}} $